# Magento - Preview product but require login to buy

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I'm actually discussing with a customer about the need to integrate social network sharing within their magentocommerce.

The customer wants a user to be able to share on facebook a product, and allow a "preview" of the product to non logged users (that may want to follow the link through facebook itself), but then require the login to purchase the item.

I told them to disable the login for the whole site, and require it only for the checkout (that's the best way also to get indexed by google), but they asked me to create some sort of preview for non-logged users, and require then a login to view the "add to cart" button.

Is it easily doable? Is it worth it? I'm still thinking the best solution would be require the login only for the checkout.

Do you have any link/demo that can show me up some sort of preview but then require a login? I'm actually thinking about the way ebay shows things to non-logged users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try to avoid littering your templates with `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` as has been previously suggested to you.

If you only have to deal with the add to cart functionality on product view, then you all you require is a little layout xml...

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <remove name="product.info.addtocart" />
</customer_logged_out>
```

Nice, clean and easy.

If however, you have to deal with site wide i.e. product view, product list etc then I would suggest you create an observer that subscribes to `catalog_product_is_salable_after`.  This event gets fired, not suprisingly, after every call to [Mage_Catalog_Model_Product isSalable](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1290) - you will therefore have an opportunity to force a product to not be salable if the customer is not logged in.

Obviously you do need create a module, but this is IMO the best option and worth the little extra effort that it takes.

So, to create the observer, you will need to add the following to the **frontend** node of your config.xml:

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_is_salable_after>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>catalog_product_is_salable_after</method>
            </yourmodule>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_is_salable_after>
</events>
```

Your observer will require the following:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalog_product_is_salable_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
             $observer->getEvent()->getData('salable')
                 ->setData('is_salable', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout change is a great tip. Never knew it even exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this adding a condition in view.phtml in your theme.
app\design\frontend\default[THEME]\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Condition:

> $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php /* // OVIDIU remove 'or  if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; */ ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Following the same logic, modify list.phtml also.

Answer (score -1):

try this:-

file: /template/catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml
location: line 52 just above

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

and around line 66, use the endif just after

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

so the whole deal looks like this beginning around line 52 (note my edit tags):

```
<!--edit-->
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?> 
<!--/edit-->
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
        <legend><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></legend>
        <span class="qty-box"><label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
        <input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>"/></span>
        <button class="form-button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></strong>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--edit-->
<?php endif; /* if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): */ ?> 
<!--/edit-->
```